# JS on Tumblr: "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy" Error

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I got a canvas jQuery pluing script on my tumblr theme,
I got this error on Chrome:

```
Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.
```

Tumblr uploads images to http://static.tumblr.com/
Even there is no different domain between files and account,
Same location, same domain...

But why do I get that error?

Any solution?

Thank you!

Comment: [subdomain != same domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: @epascarello — That should be an answer. :)

Comment: @Quentin But not a solution.. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

what epascarello said, subdomain != same domain

because you are on the same root-domain you could set the document.domain in your theme to static.tumblr.com if you dont need it for anything else (eg. tracking...)

```
document.domain = 'static.tumblr.com';
```

do that as early as can.

Comment: I put it, but I got "Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18", where do I need to put it? on "ready"? Thank you!

Comment: Before everything started document.domain equals "username.tumblr.com". It seems that policy doesnt allow subdomain changes. Any idea?

Comment: i was wrong. you only can set it to the root domain 'tumblr.com'. the would work, if both sides would set it to that root domain. can you post your plugin, and what you are trying to achieve? maybe we can help you in another way...

Comment: http://akkara.github.com/MonoJS/ this is my plugin that monolize images. I wanted to use it for background image, but that problem.. I found this: http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/ but looks problemly also.. Thank you for response!

Comment: i dont think that it is possible to work around that issue, at least i dont know, im sorry