# cross-origin sharing policy - loading colors with color-thief.js on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, colors

I'm trying to do color-analysis on images, but Chrome's dang cross-origin sharing policy gets in the way http://jsfiddle.net/mrcactu5/d6Qka/15/

```
Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.
```

I had asked on StackOverflow and got it fixed in a previous version.  http://jsfiddle.net/mrcactu5/d6Qka/6/

```
var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = '';
image.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Honeycrisp-Apple.jpg';
image.width=200;
```

Basically my script downloads links to images from Tumblr and run [color-thief.js](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/).  Simple enough, right?

```
imgs = Array(); // stores image links

$.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < data.response.length; i++){
        if(data.response[i].photos != undefined){
            //console.log(data.response[i].photos[0].alt_sizes[0].url);
            imgs.push(data.response[i].photos[0].alt_sizes[0].url);
        }

    }
}).success( function(imgs){  analyze(imgs); });
```

Comment: Use a proxy, like [Simple PHP Proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/)

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is here. What exactly is not working? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can get around cross-origin errors unless you use [document.domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.domain) setting. This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459894/js-on-tumblr-cross-origin-resource-sharing-policy-error), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474194/cross-origin-resource-sharing-policy-between-subdomains-in-js), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972049/cross-origin-data-in-html5-canvas).

You can check out a different javascript library that does something similar, demo  http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/#examples-2

Alternatively, you can [run your scripts locally](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally).